# How to send Ether from Address with private key and password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethereum, web3js, ether

I'm trying to use PHP and Cron to send Ether from an existing account using web3 or something similar, any tips on how I can accomplish this?

I have JSON in an SQL table `{"address":"0x22b853A8Df90BF9A7e21445C16FBbEaa43e0c307","password":"inu8p","privateKey":"0xb9cabca09e5cbdfb2c953d574bce5b9d837a91ffe1f3817fc6a01da63bf5ff56"}`

The problem is the JavaScript doesn't get executed with CRON.
Is there any library in Node where I can send a POST request via an API or something?

Comment: Of course the private key and the password has been modified here... At least I hope for you :)

Comment: It's an example :P

Comment: What does the "password" do? All you need in order to sign a transaction is the private key. From your example, the private key does indeed map to that address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to send a raw Ethereum transaction in PHP, so in your case I'd recommend [php-eth-raw-tx](https://github.com/Domraider/php-eth-raw-tx) package.

The usage is pretty simple:

```
$tx = new \EthereumRawTx\Transaction(
\BitWasp\Buffertools\Buffer::hex('d44d259015b61a5fe5027221239d840d92583adb'),
\BitWasp\Buffertools\Buffer::int(1 * 10**18),
);

$raw = $tx->getRaw(\BitWasp\Buffertools\Buffer::hex('b9cabca09e5cbdfb2c953d574bce5b9d837a91ffe1f3817fc6a01da63bf5ff56'));
```

In this example you send 1.0 ETH from address `0x22b853A8Df90BF9A7e21445C16FBbEaa43e0c307` (identified by a private key `0xb9cabca09e5cbdfb2c953d574bce5b9d837a91ffe1f3817fc6a01da63bf5ff56`) to address `0xd44d259015b61a5fe5027221239d840d92583adb`.

All you need to do is to create a PHP file and add it to your crontab.

See more examples here: https://github.com/Domraider/php-eth-raw-tx/tree/master/examples

Comment: Do you think you'll be able to help with this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460161/can-i-transfer-tokens-from-an-erc20-contract-using-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) or other client's RPC server. You can send a request to the RPC server via [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js), or even node's http module, but Web3 is easier.

You can then schedule this with a node cron module, like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

You will want to ensure whatever RPC server you use is setup securely, as there are active scanning and attacks against them.

A partial example:

```
//Send some eth every hour
new CronJob('* * * 1 0 0', () => {
  //The following arguments are simplified...
  web3.eth.sendTransaction({from: "0xc0ffee", to: "0xdeadbeef...", value: "1.0"}, () => {
    console.log('transaction sent');
  });
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```