# Can I transfer tokens from an ERC20 contract using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ethereum, web3js

I'm developing a website using Web3 with Metamask, users can purchase tokens by sending ETH to an address.
What I want to have done is that after the ETH is received it sends the tokens to the users ETH address automatically with backend code.

[The actual contract code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqXN8.png)

[Sending is not working unless the account is on Metamask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCWPa.png)

Any tips on how I can get it to send the tokens through the backend by specifying the private key of an address with tokens?

Comment: Questions asking for help with code need to include the code as text, not as screenshots. Please see [mcve] for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, I have written a ERC20 library for PHP.

https://www.furqansiddiqui.com/libraries/erc20-php/

https://github.com/furqansiddiqui/erc20-php

To send ERC20 tokens to an address, all you need to do is use "encodedTransferData" method and use the returning string as value for "data" param when you send Ethereum transaction.

There are other ERC20 standard methods included as well, such as name(), balanceOf(), decimals(), symbol()

Comment: I think OP has asked if he can transfer tokens using PHP, yes his current implementation is based on web3, but still OP asked for method to transfer using PHP, so why down vote?

Comment: in your package, there is no way to use infura ropsten. Can you please share the code how to connect with infura testnet?